# /sbin/ifconfig "Operation not permitted"

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, vps

Having just signed up for a VPS package, I'm trying to create a point-to-point network. I'm logged in as root, I'm fairly certain at some point ifconfig was working because I remember inspecting the network setup. However, now when I execute ifconfig - this happens:

```
# ifconfig
bash: /sbin/ifconfig: Operation not permitted

# whoami
root

# ls -lath $(which ifconfig)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67K Mar 16  2009 /sbin/ifconfig
```

What on earth have I done?

Comment: what happens if you use `sudo` anyway?

Comment: # sudo ifconfig results in 'Operation not permitted' also

Comment: what about 'cat /proc/net/dev' ?

Comment: # cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:     400       8    0    0    0     0          0         0      400       8    0    0    0     0       0          0
venet0:  946404    6600    0    0    0     0          0         0   792312    4030    0    0    0     0       0          0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had inadvertently run setcap on /sbin/ifconfig instead of another binary. The solution was:

```
setcap -r /sbin/ifconfig <cap>
```